# Bayesian Interval Estimates for Multinomial Probabilities

Tags: bayesian, inference

Can anyone point me to a reference for calculating Bayesian interval estimates for multinomial probabilities?  I am familiar with conventional methods (i.e.: Quesenberry and Hurst (1964), Goodman (1965), Bailey (1980), Fitzpatrick and Scott (1987), and Glaz and Sison (1999)).  I have found methods to calculate intervals for differences between proportions (Piegorsch and Richwine (2001)).  However, after reading for about two weeks, I cannot find a reference for Bayesian intervals for individual proportions.

Thank you very much for assistance.

Comment: Are you asking about credibility intervals?

Comment: Yes, credibility intervals.